# Why is first line of Lyman series considered largest ultraviolet wavelength in hydrogen spectrum

Tags: spectroscopy, wavelength

I was reading a book which contains a numerical question about largest wavelength of hydrogen spectrum in ultraviolet region. In the solution, it mentions the largest wavelength in ultraviolet region is the first line of Lyman series (122nm).
Also searching on google for largest wavelength of hydrogen spectrum in ultraviolet region gives 122nm (in every website).

I know about Rydberg's equation and that in Lyman series the first line will have the largest wavelength.

#### But,

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series#:%7E:text=Lines%20five%20and%20six%20can%20be%20seen%20with%20the%20naked%20eye%2C%20but%20are%20considered%20to%20be%20ultraviolet%20as%20they%20have%20wavelengths%20less%20than%20400%20nm) mentions that the line 5 and line 6 of Balmer series also fall into ultraviolet region. Further by calculating wavelengths of these line, these are greater than 122nm.

Why are all those websites and my book ignoring those lines. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Maybe I'm old school, but if it is visible it isn't ultraviolet.

Comment: I think there is no sharp boundary between between visible and not visible. It depends on person to person. Also the wikipedia article mentioned it to be UV.

Comment: Sure, but _nobody_ sees 122nm. Furthermore, it is the transition from the first excited state to the ground state, so one of the strongest lines you will see (well, not see by eye).